# GDB doesn't show object's members

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, static-libraries

I've a class `Impl` which inherites from `Base`.

A simple code snippet I'm trying to debug:

```
{
    Base* base = getObject();     // getObject() returns instance of Impl
    base->something();
}
```

When I want to inspect `base` I get:

```
p base
$1 = (Base *) 0x7fffc408edf0

p *base
$2 = {_vptr.Base = 0x7ffff74be100 <vtable for Impl+16>}
```

I'm compiling my program with `gcc` and I use `-O0 -g`. I've also tried `-ggdb3` instead of `-g` with no use.

What may be important here: my project is divided into 3 modules: executable and two static libraries. Code I'm debugging lies in one of those static libraries, and definitions of `Impl` and `Base` are in second one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `(gdb) set print object on`.

[Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Print-Settings.html):

```
set print object on
  When displaying a pointer to an object, identify the actual (derived) type
  of the object rather than the declared type, using the virtual function table.
```

Comment: This relies on the virtual function table, which doesn't exist if there are no virtual functions in Base (in the example obviously there are some).

Comment: @aferber: yes, there are some and Employed Russian's solution work :)

Answer (score 2):

gdb doesn't know your `*base` is pointing to an `Impl`, so you have to tell it:

```
p (Impl)*base
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. You probably meant `p *(Impl*)base`. That said, `set print object on` is better.

Comment: It definitely works, I actually tested it. My version works even if there are no virtual functions and therefore no virtal function table.

Comment: for me something like: `p (Impl) base` works which is pretty surprising...

Comment: Look carefully, `p (Impl)base` isn't an error, however it does something different than you think it does. Now you are no longer displaying the pointer *target* as an instance of Impl, instead you are displaying *the pointer itself* (plus whatever happens to be in the memory directly after the pointer if `sizeof(Impl) > sizeof(*Base)`) as an instance of Impl.